# How is border-style: inset supposed to look like?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `border-style: inset;` but it only renders a solid grey line. I was expecting it would render a nice inset looking line or something.

Comment: The rendering depends, somewhat, on the browser in question. It also depends on how thick the border is. You should see the effect if make the border really fat. You'll also have to play with the `border-color`, `inset` will adjust it in two directions to produce the inset effect.

Comment: Yeah!! I agree with @mu. If you wanna get more look about it you should use the image instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can see various border styles in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hey Caner, your link seems to be broken -- can you please fix it (or attach the image to the answer instead)? Thanks :)

Comment: @tahatmat I added the picture